# How can a constructor call lead Visual Studio 2019 to issue a C26444 warning?

Tags: c++

The best that I know, a constructor is of void type.  Given the code as specified below, why would the Visual Studio 2019 editor flag the indicated invocation of the constructor with a C26444 warning?

**Here is the relevant implementation source code:**

```
#pragma once

#include "Class_dB_CG.h"

CG::CG() {}

CG::~CG() {}

CG::CG(const CG& rhs) {}

CG::CG(ER* e)

{

CG();       ***//warning on this line***

er = e;

}


**The header file is here:**

#pragma once

#include "Class_dB_ER.h"

class CG

{

private:

ER*   er = 0;

public:

CG();

~CG();

CG(const CG& rhs);

CG(ER* e);

};
```

Comment: I don't get any warnings: https://rextester.com/ZYTKF38159

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26444?view=vs-2019 C26444 means "Unnamed (that is, temporary) objects with non-trivial behavior may point to ... inefficient code that allocates and immediately throws away resources"  So you are creating a temporart object and not assigning it to a variable so it get immediately destroyed.

Comment: when you get a warning or error on a specific line + column it means that the issue is on or before that position. In your case it is likely before that line (in type ER)

Comment: please supply the contents of "Class_dB_ER.h"

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
CG::CG(ER* e)
{ 
  CG(); // warning on this line
  er = e;
}
```

you are not calling the constructor. You are just creating a temporary object that gets discarded. This is probably what the warning is referring to.

If you want to call the constructor, you can do it like this:

```
CG::CG(ER* e) : CG()
{
  er = e;
}
```

Comment: not disagreeing with you. But there is no warning when using ER as an alias for int. The warning must have something to do with the type ER (which we don't know)

Comment: @engf-010 Oops, I tried `int` and forgot to change it back to `ER`. Fixed, thanks. I'd say it should be a warning regardless of what `ER` is.

Comment: still ,the warning must originate in ER

Comment: totally agreed. but the OP gets the warning ,while I don't. which makes me wonder what is in ER.

Comment: OK.  So the construction I gave is an error in syntax.

Comment: Technically, it's not an error. It just doesn't mean a constructor call.

Comment: @wrb: if you give us the defintion of ER we might discover why you get the warning while we don't.

Comment: class ER
{
public:
    ER();
    ~ER();                                                                                                               
}

Comment: The point is that on instantiation, CG is passed a pointer (or reference) to a previously instantiated ER.  CG does some work that is of value, while ER is a mechanism of error reporting.  So, when a CG method encounters an error, the pointer provides means to invoke ER methods to report the error.  The ER object is instantiated by a top-level routine, and that routine passes the ER pointer to several other objects, each of a different class.

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about any of that as far as this warning is concerned.

Comment: @wrb: Still no error. strange. You could try "Run Code analysis"

Comment: Actually, following the advice of @cigien, the warning went away, and I was not particularly worried with the warning, since my code runs as expected.  I just like to be aware of the details, and wherever possible, to eliminate syntax that annoys the compiler.  Thanks.